# Convert list to matrix (python)

Tags: python, list, matrix

I would like to convert a list to a matrix so that I can use the .append function the way I need it.
`list = ["1", "2", "3"]` should become `[["1", "2", "3"]]`.

Then when I use `list.append(["4", "5", "6"])` it will become `[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]` instead of `["1", "2", "3", ["4", "5", "6"]]`.

How can I do this?

Comment: `list =[ ["1", "2", "3"]]`, then you can append lists. like `list.append(["4", "5", "6"])` which gives you expected result

Comment: Thanks got it. Tried this myself in the json.dump([list],file) but it didn't work here (which I understand now). Simply added a definition (list2 = [list] before the son.dump and now it works. Thank!

Comment: no need to create new `list2`. Simply `list = [list]` and then you can append.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this (a matrix as a list of lists):

```
In [1]: matrix = [[1,2,3]]

In [2]: matrix
Out[2]: [[1, 2, 3]]

In [3]: matrix.append([4,5,6])

In [4]: matrix
Out[4]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Well I can't change my 'list'. I get a huge list every 30 min via my code and wish to append it. I check if the file is empty or not so it can first print a list and then use the append function to add further list resulting in a matrix.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done very easily:

```
def list_to_matrix(lst):
    return [lst]
```

Usage:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> lst = list_to_matrix(lst)
>>> lst
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

If we have cases where we might get things that are already in list-of-list form, we can add a little more robustness by doing this:

```
from collections import Iterable

def list_to_matrix(lst):
    if lst:
        return lst if all(isinstance(item, Iterable) and not isinstance(item, str) for item in lst) else [lst]
    else:
        # returns empty matrix if input list was empty
        return [[]]
```

Note that this method is pretty fragile, but at least allows you to safely pass either a base list or a list of list form blindly and get back the correct thing.

Answer (score 2):

This works for any objects in list. It gives to every object its coordinates in pseudo 2d list:

```
def to_matrix(l, n):
    return [(x[0] / n, x[0] % n , x) for x in l]
```

The output for `to_matrix([objects], 3)` would be:

```
[(0, 0, some_object),
 (0, 1, some_object),
 (0, 2, some_object),
 (1, 0, some_object),
 (1, 1, some_object),
 (1, 2, some_object),
 (2, 0, some_object),
 (2, 1, some_object),
 (2, 2, some_object)]
```

If you need a real 2d array, this code will do the job:

```
def toMatrix(l, n):
    matrix = []
    for i in range (0, len(l), n):
        matrix.append(l[i:i+n])

    return matrix
```

Comment: thanks so much, this helped me solve my issue of converting a 100 item list into a matrix of 10x10, now i'm going to see how to convert this matrix into a gray-scale image

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_matrix(lst, list_of_dimensions):
    n_dimensions = len(list_of_dimensions)
    n_elements = len(lst)
    check_elements = 1
    matrix = []
    index_list = 0
    for i in list_of_dimensions:
        check_elements *= i
    if check_elements != n_elements:
        return "List elements Not Equal Product Of  Dimensions"
    for dimension in list_of_dimensions:
        sub_lst = []
        for x in range(dimension):
            sub_lst.append(lst[index_list])
            index_list += 1
        matrix.append(sub_lst)

    return matrix
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).